# acts_as_commentable examples?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-commentable

I have a model that I want to be commentable. I am having difficulty creating a form on my model's 'show' view that will allow comments to be created. I am not finding any good or useful examples. Can anyone point me to or show me an example of how to do this?

Example:

A simple blog application. I have a model called Post. It is commentable. So on the 'show' view I want to show a Post and, at the bottom, have the fields that, when completed and submitted, create a new comment associated with the post and put it in the database.

Sounds straightforward and I have it working so I can display comments that I have seeded. I just can't get a form to work to put new ones in. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/16 might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very, very basic stuff and you clearly need some better structure and approach to your learning. Buying a book, such as [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails), is the only real way to learn, otherwise you'll wander from problem to problem without ever actually learning anything well.

Say you have a post that you want to comment.

```
#routes.rb
map.resources :posts do |post|
  post.resources :comments
end

#post_controller.rb
def show
  @post.find params[:id]
  @comment = @post.comments.new
end

#posts/show.html.erb
<%- form_for [@post, @comment] do |f|-%>
  <%= f.text_area :body -%>
  <%= f.submit -%>
<%- end -%>

#comments_controller
def create
  @post = @post.find params[:post_id]
  @comment = @post.comments.new params[:comment]
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @post
```

Comment: I appreciate the info and your criticism. I will look into that book. I guess what was throwing me off here was that i was using one model from with the show view of another. I guess it isn't as difficult as I assumed it to be. Thanks again.

Comment: I think I am almost there but the route is breaking. How would the map.resources statement translate into the Rails 3 way of routing? The changes in Rails 3 is a lot of what is giving me trouble.

Comment: Hey NJ. Sorry I didn't get back to you. I haven't used rails 3 yet so don't know of the routing changes. If you include them here I'll put them in my answer in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 28):

Lets assume a Post model. Make sure, you have

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_commentable
end
```

then in the view of say Post#show

```
  <%= form_tag "/posts/add_new_comment" do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "id", post.id %>
    <%= text_area_tag "comment[comment]" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Post Comment" %>
  <% end %>
```

then in the PostController

```
  def add_new_comment
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.comments << Post.new(params[:comment])
    redirect_to :action => :show, :id => post
  end
```

and in routes.rb

```
  match "/posts/add_new_comment" => "posts#add_new_comment", :as => "add_new_comment_to_posts", :via => [:post]
```

Hope this gets u up and running.

Comment: A great answer without the snark (as seen above).  Much appreciated.

Comment: In the controller code, the 'Post.new' should not be 'Comment.new' instead??

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I want to throw in my solution as well as the gem's README is still unhelpful after all these years. It builds upon @Kunday's answer. The following will be a tutorial to use the act_as_commentable gem to...

1. Allow users to create comments under each post.
2. Show all comments belonging to a post.

This assumes that you already have a working "blog", whether it be pictures or posts. Install gem, then run `rails g comment` to get started.

**Allow users to create comments under each post.**

First, inside the model that you want to use commentable gem, add the following line as suggested in the gem's README.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  acts_as_commentable
end
```

Then create a new comment controller with the `create` action. Please note that the `:authenticate_user!` is part of devise which is a gem for creating easy authentication. `current_user` is also part of devise as a helper. It is needed if you want to display the user's name/email under the comment body.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
    comment = post.comments.build(comment_params)
    comment.user = current_user

    if comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Comment has been created."
      redirect_to post
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Comment has not been created."
    end
  end

  private    
    def comment_params
      params.permit(:comment)
    end
end
```

Next, set up the routes. It's just this. This means that when someone sends a post request to comments, we will run to create action inside the comments controller.

```
post 'comments' => 'comments#create', as: "create_comment"
```

The `as: "create_comment"` gives it an alias, so you can do `create_comment_path`. Now, on the show view of Post, we'll add the form. The divs will help you add css.

```
<div class="comment-section">
  <%= form_tag create_comment_path, method: "post" do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "id", @post.id %>
      <%= text_area_tag :comment %>
      <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Now to show each comment under the Post show view.**

The divs will help you add css, `comment.user.name` will work if your User class has a name column. Else, change it to `email` or whatever identifier you choose to use.

```
<div class="comment_list">
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.comment %> <br>
      <%= comment.user.name %> <br>
        <br>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And finally, in order for @comments to exist in the show page, go to your Post controller, and under show, add the following:

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments.all
  end
```

This should be good for the requirements. Good luck.

Comment: This post just saved me. The instructions on the gem page don't mention that a user has to be assigned to a comment before saving it, and I was getting an error. Thanks!